# I want to 2 decimal points result for predicts on Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, floating-point, predict, sklearn-pandas

My outputs have too much decimal points. But I want to 2 points float results. Can you help me?

EX: `42.44468745 -> 42.44`

```
y_pred=ml.predict(x_test)
print(y_pred)
```

Output:

```
[42.44468745 18.38280575  7.75539511 19.05326276 11.87002186 26.89180941
 18.97589775 22.01291508  9.08079557  6.72623692 21.81657224 22.51415263
 24.46456776 13.75392096 21.57583275 25.73401908 30.95880457 11.38970094
  7.28188274 21.98202474 17.24708345 38.7390475  12.68345506 11.2247757
  5.32814356 10.41623796  7.30681434]
```

Comment: Does `np.round(y_pred, 2)` work ?

Comment: Do you want to just **print** to 2 decimal places, or change the precision of `y_pred` to 2 decimal places?

Comment: @fam-woodpecker Unfortunately, no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't post all of your code, I can only give you a general answer.

There are several ways to get two decimals.

For example:

```
num = 1.223362719

print('{:.2f}'.format(num))

print('%.2f' % num)

print(round(num, 2))

print(f"{num:.2f}")
```

You will get `1.22` as the result of any of these.

------------------Update------------------

Thanks for commenting, and I have updated to deal with your problem.

Using numpy could help you when your data OP is using an ndarray.

You can use `data= np.around(a, n)` # a is the data that needs to be decimal processed, and n is the reserved number.

Example:

```
    import numpy as np
    data= np.around(1.223362719, 2)
```

You will also get `1.22` as the result.

Comment: I think you better add a `numpy` solution too since the data OP is using is an `ndarray`

Comment: And also maybe add `print(f"{num:.2f}")`.

Comment: @LTX Thanks for helping. I used your updated codes and worked that

Comment: @rickhg12hs I tried on print but didn't work

Comment: @Cataldirect [Format strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#tut-f-strings) `f"` should work on recent versions of Python.

Answer (score 0):

Use `round(num, round_decimal)`
For example:

```
num = 42.44468745

print(round(num, 2))
```

Output:

```
42.44
```